# How can I join 6 tables that are getting their records multiplied? Metabase

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

POSTGRES SQL /// READ ONLY   ///  METABASE

I was using a simple INNER JOIN to join the tables, but the records multiplied and I ended up with 150000 records when I only had ~450. So I check on SOverflow to get an answer and I found that by subquerying I could avoid the multiplied records.

As you can say by me being here asking for help, I did the joins it until the fourth, then It multiplies again despite using a subquery.

Let me explain myself, the first two JOINS can get "inner joined" without any multiplied record.

The "third join" does get the records multiply if I do an "inner join", so I use a subquery as you see, and it works perfectly. After that I try to do another JOIN but the values get multiplied again, despite using a subquery.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    "public"."checklist_checklistsectionitem"
INNER JOIN 
    "public"."checklist_noncompliance" "Checklist Noncompliance" 
         ON "public"."checklist_checklistsectionitem"."id" = "Checklist Noncompliance"."item_id" 
INNER JOIN 
    "public"."checklist_checklistitem" "Checklist Checklistitem - Check List Item" 
         ON "public"."checklist_checklistsectionitem"."check_list_item_id" = "Checklist Checklistitem - Check List Item"."id" 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         "checklistitem_id",
         "operation_id" 
     FROM
         "public"."checklist_checklistitem_operations") AS "coltab" ON
        "coltab"."checklistitem_id" = "Checklist Checklistitem - Check List Item"."id"
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "public"."operations_operation"."id"
--, others columns...
        FROM
            "public"."operations_operation"   
    ) AS "coltab_2" ON
        "coltab_2"."id" = "coltab"."operation_id"
```

NOTICE that this last Inner doesn't work (it multiplies the record by a lot), and the big issue here is that after that inner join I have to do another 3 more joins.

The tables have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships

Hope you can save me, if you need more info you can demand it.

[image]

Comment: You **really** should not use identifiers like `"Checklist Checklistitem - Check List Item"` as table aliases - that kinds defeats the point of using aliases in the first place: they're meant to be _succinct_ identifiers to reduce the amount of keyboard typing and reading (and horizontal scrolling...) needed to read and understand your query.

Comment: Also, you don't need to put every identifier `"in quotes"` if they don't need escaping, like `public` or `coltab`.

Comment: _"that this last Inner doesn't work (it multiplies the record by a lot)"_ - this is indicative of doing a `JOIN` on a non-unique (i.e. non-`PRIMARY KEY`) column. The `ON` predicate in a `JOIN` _should_ (for the most part) only be done as equi-joins from an FK to a PK (or UK) - all other types of join conditions are typically painful for the engine to evaluate (i.e. they're slow) - and, as in your case, often result in row _explosions_.

Comment: Something about the noncompliance not being used anywhere else screams "this should be a union" with a sum applied over the two unions counts or an exists instead of a join or just a lot of "OR exists"